# MyBatis binding - evaluate static java expression

Tags: bind, mybatis

I'd like to use static java expression

```
Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").format(new Date()))
```

in MyBatis binding:

```
  <select id="getInvalid" resultMap="invoiceData" parameterType="cz.px.iis.dto.PxSqlCriteria">
    <bind name="month" value="Integer.parseInt(new DateFormat.getInstance(&quot;yyyyMM&quot;).format(new Date())" />
    SELECT FISB00.*,
    <include refid="cz.pse.agata.commons.dto.mapper.LegalPersonMapper.fullLegalPerson"/>
    from fisb00
    left outer join FEPO00 on  right(I0IDMA, 8) = POICO
    <include refid="cz.pse.agata.commons.dto.mapper.LegalPersonMapper.joinTables"/>
    where I0PLAT='A' and I0MFFA >= #{month}
    and I0IDMA not in 
       (select PUEXID from fepu00) 
    <include refid="cz.pse.agata.commons.mapper.CommonStatements.whereCriteria"/>
  </select>
```

When I use it as it is, I get

```
There is no getter for property named 'Integer' in 'class cz.px.iis.dto.PxSqlCriteria'
```

When I try to use **@** to annotate the class names as a class I get exceptions like

```
Error evaluating expression '@Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").format(new Date()))'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: @Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").format(new Date())) [org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ParseException: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 18.
Was expecting one of:
"." ...
"@" ...
]
```

What is proper syntax for such expression?

Comment: Let us know your mapper file declration

Comment: @KarthikPrasad question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use bind you can directly use below EL

```
${new Integer(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").format(new java.util.Date()))}
```

Your Query would be as below

```
SELECT FISB00.*,
    <include refid="cz.pse.agata.commons.dto.mapper.LegalPersonMapper.fullLegalPerson"/>
    from fisb00
    left outer join FEPO00 on  right(I0IDMA, 8) = POICO
    <include refid="cz.pse.agata.commons.dto.mapper.LegalPersonMapper.joinTables"/>
    where I0PLAT='A' and I0MFFA >= ${new Integer(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").format(new java.util.Date()))}
    and I0IDMA not in 
       (select PUEXID from fepu00) 
    <include refid="cz.pse.agata.commons.mapper.CommonStatements.whereCriteria"/>
  </select>
```

Comment: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: ${Integer.parseInt(new DateFormat.getInstance("yyyyMM").format(new Date())} [org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ParseException: Encountered "$" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    ":" ...
    "not" ...
    "+" ...

Comment: Is is possible to use parameter/bind in such piece of code, ie. something like *${new Integer(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").format(#{myDate}))}*? But with above code I get *Malformed OGNL expression: new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("YYYY").format(#{date [org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 52.*